# MySQL how to implement weekdays

Tags: mysql

Hi I need to implement following solution, advise appreciated

Children attend the play scheme on certain days of the 
week, each day being represented by its first three letters (e.g., ‘Mon’ for ‘Monday’). If a child 
attends every day of the week, then there will be five entries for that child.
How to implement it ?

Comment: What have you tried, and what problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE child 
(
  child_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  child_name VARCHAR (30),
  CONSTRAINT child_pk PRIMARY KEY (child_id)
);
```

-- populate it

```
INSERT INTO child VALUES (1, 'John Doe');
INSERT INTO child VALUES (2, 'Jean Doe');
```

-- then

```
CREATE TABLE childplay 
(
  child_id INTEGER,
  play_date DATE,
  CONSTRAINT child_play_pk PRIMARY KEY (child_id, play_date),
  -- Or you could use an AUTO_INCREMENT childplay_id field and have
  -- a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on (child_id, play_date). I think the 
  -- natural key is better in this case!
  CONSTRAINT fk_cp_child FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES child (child_id)
);
```

See end of answer for table data (also, see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=690b9fc9b3cb9b21250f749384a98e08)).

Then run a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  child_id, 
  DAYNAME(play_date) AS pd,
  LEFT(DAYNAME(play_date), 3) AS pd3
  FROM childplay
ORDER BY child_id, play_date;
```

Result:

```
child_id    pd          pd3
       1    Saturday    Sat
       1    Sunday      Sun
       1    Monday      Mon
       1    Tuesday     Tue    
-- other results snipped - see fiddle
```

You should always store `DATE`s as `DATE`s - use the appropriate datatype at all times and then derive/calculate the values you want to display **from** these correct datatypes.

=========== data for childplay table =================

```
INSERT INTO childplay VALUES (1, '2019-07-20');
INSERT INTO childplay VALUES (1, '2019-07-21');
INSERT INTO childplay VALUES (1, '2019-07-22');
INSERT INTO childplay VALUES (1, '2019-07-23');
INSERT INTO childplay VALUES (1, '2019-07-24');
INSERT INTO childplay VALUES (1, '2019-07-25');
INSERT INTO childplay VALUES (2, '2019-07-20');
INSERT INTO childplay VALUES (2, '2019-07-21');
INSERT INTO childplay VALUES (2, '2019-07-22');
INSERT INTO childplay VALUES (2, '2019-07-23');
INSERT INTO childplay VALUES (2, '2019-07-24');
```

Comment: Thanks. but if I want to have Child table, column childplay referenced by Playday table fk_cp ?

Comment: Don't really understand what you're asking here. What is it you want to do that you can't do with the schema that I've given you? What fields would you put in a `playday` table?